# How to unit test observer called from a private method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a view model class, `SampleViewModel`, that has an observer, `DataSourceObserver`, whose event's (e.g. `onDataUpdated`) are triggered from a private method of the view model's data source class.

I am trying to add a unit test for how the view model's observer handles the `onDataUpdated`.

```
@HiltViewModel
public class SampleViewModel extends ViewModel {

  private final @NonNull ViewModelDataSource viewModelDataSource;

  private final @NonNull ViewModelDataSource.DataSourceObserver observer = new ViewModelDataSource.DataSourceObserver() {
    @Overrode
    public void onDataUpdated(){
      // some sort of handling
    }
  };

  @Inject
  public SampleViewModel(final @NonNull ViewModelDataSource dataSource){
    viewModelDataSource = dataSource;
    viewModelDataSource.setObserver(observer);
  }
}

public class ViewModelDataSource{
  public interface DataSourceObserver {
    void onDataUpdated();
  }

  private final ContactObservers.Observer contactObserver = new ContactObservers.Observer(){
    @Override
    public void onContactUpdated(){
      if (myObserver != null){
        myObserver.onDataUpdated();
      }
    }
  };

  private @Nullable DataSourceObserver myObserver;
  
  @Inject
  public ViewModelDataSource(){
    // other initialization here
  }

  public void setObserver(DataSourceObserver observer){
    myObserver = observer;
  }
}
```

I have Mockito for mocking/stubbing objects, but I have no idea how to approach such a problem so that I can at least trigger something like `observer.onDataUpdated` and verify the method calls within the handling of `onDataUpdated`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to use `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the initialized observer in the view model when `viewModelDataSource.setObserver(observer);` is called.

In my unit test:

```
ArgumentCaptor<ViewModelDataSource.DataSourceObserver> capturedObserver = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ViewModelDataSource.DataSourceObserver.class);
SampleViewModel viewModel = new SimpleViewModel( ...);
assertNotNull(capturedObserver);
```